# Can you control the output of OMXPlayer?

Tags: raspbian

Can you control the output of OMXPlayer? I want to be at the top left hand side of the screen and a specific size. The default behivior is to just display the video at the maximum resolution.

Comment: Because it hijacks the GPU completely I don't think you can run it windowed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `--win "x1 y1 x2 y2"` flag on latest version, which play the video in windowed mode.